# How to use regular models/libraries along with package in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble using packages in codeigniter.

My folder layout is:

```
/applications
   /regular_application1
   /regular_application2
   /common_pkg
```

In common_pkg, I have models that I want both applications to be able to use. In order to load the package, I added the route to it in $autoload['packages']-

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(FCPATH.'applications/common_pkg/');
```

This works fine, in both applications in any controller I can now load the models using:

```
$this->load->model("Balance_model");
```

The problem is that after this, I want to load  a library from within my regular_applicationx. So I call from within my controller (the controller is in regular_applicationx:

```
$this->load->library("Selections_library");
```

But when I try to use the library, I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Selections::$Selections_library
```

I'm surmising from the above that once I set my package to common_pkg in the autoload, CodeIgniter is only looking there for libraries and models. Is there any way to load both from the regular application and common_pkg?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it defined Selections in library??

Comment: Selections_library is a class in libraries in regular_application1. It's format is correct- <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Selections_library {....

Comment: Look that's irrelevant. It loads the library fine when I don't put FCPATH.'applications/common_pkg/ in the autoload. But then I need to load other models from common, so I do need that package.